# Shouldn't display the row after specific length like after 10 characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has some data. I don't want to display the row after 10 characters. I've written code like this. It is working when my data is not in array format. Like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column':['PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON', 'PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS', 'Dss', 'Python R DSS', 'PYTHON']
    })
```

but when I have arrays

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column':[['"PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON"'], 'PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS', 'Dss', 'Python R DSS', 'PYTHON']
    })
```

then I get an error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Can you please help me with this?

Here is my complete code:

```
   import pandas as pd, numpy as np
   import collections
   from collections import OrderedDict
   df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[['"PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON"'], 'PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS', 'Dss', 'Python R DSS', 'PYTHON']})
   
   df['column'] = (df['column'].str.split()
                                 .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                                 .str.join(' '))

   df['column'] = df['column'].str[:10]

   print (df)
```

Comment: Please explain your lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the first column value, which is a list, unlike the others which are strings.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
df = pd.DataFrame( {'column':[['"PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON"'], 'PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS', 'Dss', 'Python R DSS', 'PYTHON'] })
df
```

```
                      column
0    ["PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON"]
1  PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS
2                         Dss
3                Python R DSS
4                      PYTHON
```

Breaking down your cascaded operation to take a look at only the split operation

```
df_temp =df['column'].str.split() 
df_temp
```

```
0                                  NaN
1    [PYTHON, R, JAVA, PYTHON, C, DSS]
2                                [Dss]
3                     [Python, R, DSS]
4                             [PYTHON]
Name: column, dtype: object
```

We see that the first value is `NaN`. If we do `type(df_temp[0])` we find that it is a `float` value. Therefore, the float error message.

You can either do some pre-cleaning before passing the data or if you have to stick to the current data format, here is a solution

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import collections
from collections import OrderedDict
df = pd.DataFrame( {'column':[['"PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON"'], 'PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS', 'Dss', 'Python R DSS', 'PYTHON'] })

# converting the list into a string
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: str(''.join(x))[1:-1] if isinstance(x, list) else x)# [1,-1] is to remove `"` from the newly created string


# perform your indended operation
df['column'] = (df['column'].str.split()
                                .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                                .str.join(' '))

df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : x[:10].split(','))

print (df)
```

Result

```
        column
0  [PYTHON R J]
1  [PYTHON R J]
2         [Dss]
3  [Python R D]
4      [PYTHON]
```

Replace the last line with

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : ['"' + v + '"' for v in x[:10].split(',')])
```

```
          column
0  ["PYTHON R J"]
1  ["PYTHON R J"]
2         ["Dss"]
3  ["Python R D"]
4      ["PYTHON"]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. but df = pd.DataFrame( {'coloumn':[['"PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON"'], ['"PYTHON R JAVA PYTHON C DSS"'], ['"Dss"'], ['"Python R DSS"'], ['"PYTHON"']] }) if this is my input i wat out as coloumn
0  ["PYTHON R J"]
1  ["PYTHON R J"}
2         ["Dss"]
3  ["Python R D"]
4      ["PYTHON"]

Comment: in array only I want output

Comment: You didn't provide any expected output. That's why I went with your initial code logic. I have made the changes to convert it into a list. You can do the formatting or changes as per your requirement.

Comment: Hey it worked and sorry for didn't provide my expected output..  but wat if I want  Double quotes inside array like ["PYHTON R J"].. Please let me know this